# hasOwnProperty is undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, babeljs

I am trying to use `lodash-es` package. Since it is an ES6 module, Babel transpiles it for Jest.

The Babel config is:

```
{
    "env": {
        "test": {
            "plugins": [
                "babel-plugin-rewire",
                "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
                "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
            ],
            "ignore": [
                "i18n/*.js"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But I have been getting

> Function.prototype.toString requires that 'this' be a Function at toString

error as I try to run the tests.

I found the [file](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/es/_baseIsNative.js#L23) from where the error was coming and it seems like

`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` is `undefined`.

I have included the specific part of the code below.

```
var funcProto = Function.prototype, objectProto = Object.prototype;
var funcToString = funcProto.toString;
var hasOwnProperty = objectProto.hasOwnProperty;
var reIsNative = RegExp('^' +
  // here hasOwnProperty is undefined leading to the error
  funcToString.call(hasOwnProperty).replace(reRegExpChar, '\\$&')
  .replace(/hasOwnProperty|(function).*?(?=\\\()| for .+?(?=\\\])/g, '$1.*?') + '$'
);
```

It is a weird error. I tried running `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` in `node` and it is working alright. I am trying to figure out how it is evaluating to `undefined` in this case.

Comment: why you think `hasOwnProperty` has anything to do with `Function.prototype.toString`? do you have some code not shown?

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/es/_baseIsNative.js#L27 the error is because in line 27, the hasOwnProperty is `undefined`.

Comment: can you also check what is `objectProto`?

Comment: @appleapple it is a file inside node_module. The error occurs when I do `yarn test`. I tried doing `console.error(objectProto)` but that isn't showing up in the console. But it cannot be undefined since `objectProto.hasOwnPropert`y didn't result in an error.

Comment: no, it can be `undefined` (although unlikely to happens on `Object.prototype`), just try `let x = {}; console.log(x.a);` , it'd return undefined without result in error.

Comment: @appleapple `objectProto` cannot be undefined. `var x = undefined; x.someproperty` will throw an error.

Comment: oh, I think you mean `objectProto.hasOwnPropert` cannot be `undefined`, sorry.

Comment: hasOwnProperty generally returns boolean value if that particular object has a property declared. objectProto.In your case, hasOwnProperty is not getting such property to evaluate

Comment: var v={
    "env": {...       and Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(v, 'env');

Comment: @Rashedul.Rubel the problem is hasOwnProperty is undefined in the above code. It may be a Babel issue.

Comment: Lodash code was written to be trouble-free. Function.prototype.toString and Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty are expected to exist in any reasonable JS engine. That you have this problem means two things, either these prototypes were messed up or the code was transformed by Babel in a way objectProto refers not to Object.prototype but something else. At this point the question cannot be answered without https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . From what you posted, plugin-transform-runtime is the first thing to suspect.

Comment: @EstusFlask that make sense. But a MCVE might not be possible in this case. Do you know a way I can know what `Object` is referring to? `console.log` didn't work, writing using fs.writeFile didn't work as well.

Comment: Add `console.log(eval('Object.prototype') === objectProto)` to that place to make sure if it's Babel's fault.  console.log is inefficient way to debug, you can debug things in Node with Chrome. This includes Jest, something like `node --inspect-brk node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js`. For MCVE you need the most simple project that derives from your current setup and still reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hah. I mean that Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty and Function.prototype.toString are the last things that should cause problems under normal circumstances and wouldn't be used in such popular library if they were flaky. In your case the problem is supposedly that you're using Babel with incompatible config to process lodash-es, while it's usually processed only by Webpack in browser apps and is used as native ES module in Node.

Comment: @EstusFlask check out my answer. It was nonetheless a bad idea to name a variable after a property especially when javscript allows subscript access to variables/properties.

Comment: @AmitJoki No, it's certainly not a bad practice. This is what's usually done with destructuring like `let { hasOwnProperty } = objectProto`. You wouldn't ever have such problem if the script weren't processed in a wrong way.

Comment: @EstusFlask open up the console and type `hasOwnProperty` and press enter. It will evaluate to `window.hasOwnProperty`. If the same property name is used as a variable, the least I'd expect is some sort of namespacing so there wouldn't be any confusion :)

Comment: I guess this was confusing to debug but this was a very edge case. This concern would require to constantly overthink var naming that wouldn't normally cause shadowing problems. `length` is another fine name that makes sense in some contexts I used more than once but there's `window.length` too.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of debugging, I found out the issue.

Babel converts the snippet below from

```
var funcProto = Function.prototype, objectProto = Object.prototype;
var funcToString = funcProto.toString;
var hasOwnProperty = objectProto.hasOwnProperty;
var reIsNative = RegExp('^' +
  // here hasOwnProperty is undefined leading to the error
  funcToString.call(hasOwnProperty).replace(reRegExpChar, '\\$&')
  .replace(/hasOwnProperty|(function).*?(?=\\\()| for .+?(?=\\\])/g, '$1.*?') + '$'
);
```

is transpiled to the below:

```
var funcProto = Function.prototype, objectProto = Object.prototype;
var funcToString = _get__("funcProto").toString;
var hasOwnProperty = _get__("objectProto").hasOwnProperty;
var reIsNative = RegExp('^' + _get__("funcToString").call(_get__("hasOwnProperty")).replace(_get__("reRegExpChar"), '\\$&').replace(/hasOwnProperty|(function).*?(?=\\\()| for .+?(?=\\\])/g, '$1.*?') + '$');
```

The culprit was how Babel references its variables but more so, it was how Lodash named its variable after properties.

The variable `hasOwnProperty` is referenced as `_get__("hasOwnProperty")` which seems to remove the variable name that is similar to well-known Object properties.

So, `_get__("hasOwnProperty")` was `undefined` while, if it was accessed normally, like `hasOwnProperty` it had the function alright.

**So, the fix:**

I just renamed `hasOwnProperty` to `hasOwnProp` and bingo! It worked.

Comment: Did you file a bug with Babel for this?

Comment: @Bergi I just figured this out. I'll file one soon.

Comment: Glad you sorted this out. This seems to be purely babel-plugin-rewire's fault because `_get__` belongs to it. It's not an official plugin so Babel isn't responsible for this mess. And FWIW it probably doesn't need to be used with Jest at all, Jest already handles module mocking.

Comment: @EstusFlask uh. I'll see if the build is successful without the plugin.

Comment: @EstusFlask yes, removing that changed nothing at all and solved the problem of not having to rename the variables in a node_module package as well :)

Comment: @Bergi guess this is not Babel related, but an independent Babel plugin. I'll file it there instead.